# What does "affect component" mean in this article on well-being?

Tags: emotion, terminology, well-being

> Previous research lends support to the view that the **negative affect component** of well-being is strongly associated with neuroticism and that **positive affect component** has a similar association with extraversion. This research also supports the view that positive emotions—central components of well-being—are not merely the opposite of negative emotions, but are independent dimensions of mental health that can, and should be fostered.

Emphasis mine. [Source.](https://www.cdc.gov/hrqol/wellbeing.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the CDC page you linked states,

> Well-being integrates mental health (mind) and physical health (body) resulting in more holistic approaches to disease prevention and health promotion.

Mental health and physical health are the 2 main components to well-being, and both these components have components within them.

Mental health will have [**positive affects** and **negative affects**](https://www.verywellmind.com/positive-affect-and-stress-3144628) as 2 of its components.